# The Čech-Stone compactification of the real line

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The Čech-Stone compactification of the real line (with discrete topology) $\beta{\mathbb{R}}$ is not countable.  I want to investigate to some properties of $\beta{\mathbb{R}}$  and the remainder $\beta{\mathbb{R}}\setminus\mathbb{R}$.  I think the remainder is not Lindelöf. How can I proof this?  And what about the metrizability of $\beta{\mathbb{R}}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}\beta\Bbb R$ is not even first countable, let alone metrizable: $\cl_{\beta\Bbb R}\Bbb Z$ is homeomorphic to $\beta\Bbb N$, and $\beta\Bbb N$ contains no convergent sequences. Corollary 3.7 in [this paper](http://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1271&context=hmc_fac_pub) by Henriksen and Isbell shows that $\beta\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb R$ is Lindelöf. Both of these statements hold both for the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ and for the discrete topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Interesting. Uncountable set with the discrete topology is Lindelöf...

Comment: @Asaf: No, the Čech-Stone remainder of an uncountable discrete space is Lindelöf, because every discrete space is metrizable.

Comment: I see. That makes much more sense!

Comment: Thanks so much Prof. Scott. It was very useful for me.

Comment: @ege: Glad to hear it; you’re very welcome.