# Is $[0,1]$ the Stone-Čech compactification of $(0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology, compactification

In [this note](http://ericmoorhouse.org/handouts/stone-cech.pdf) by G. Eric Moorhouse, which appears to be some course notes handout, it is stated on page 3:

> The [two-point] above is the Stone-Čech compactification of $(0,1)≃\mathbb{R}$;that is, $\beta\mathbb{R} ≃ [0, 1]$. This is the most general compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ in a sense that we proceed to describe.

Then he argues, complete with diagrams, that for every embedding of $(0,1)$, there is a unique extension

On the other hand, it was my understand, as similar to how it is set out by Henno Brandsma in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1790467/16490), that the Stone-Čech compactification does not generally admit an explicit description, only existence proofs using the axiom of choice. And moreover we can say that it has cardinality $2^{2^\mathfrak{C}}$ (or at least $2^\mathfrak{c}$ I'm not sure) so there's no way that $[0,1]$ could be homeomorphic to $\beta\mathbb{R}.$ Also, as stated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35310/16490), no sequence in $X$ will have its limit in $\beta X\setminus X$, whereas the endpoints of $[0,1]$ are sequential limit points of $(0,1)$.

So what's going on here? Probably just a mistake by Moorhouse, right?

Comment: Looks like a big mistake.

Comment: For instance $\{(t,\sin\frac1t):0\lt t\lt1\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ which is homeomorphic to $(0,1),$ and its closure in $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is a compactification of $(0,1).$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Moorhouse is just wrong.  Not every map $(0,1)\to Y$ extends continuously to $[0,1]$ as his pictures suggest.  For instance, as you approach the ends of the curve, the curve could oscillate infinitely so that the limit of $f(t)$ as $t$ approaches $0$ (or $1$) does not exist.

Comment: @bof See the disclaimer here: http://ericmoorhouse.org/handouts/
I've alerted Dr. Moorhouse of the error. His website contains great resources...please inform him of any other errors you may find so that these resources can improve. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

By definition, any map $(0,1)\to X$ where $X$ is compact Hausdorff should factor through $\beta (0,1)$. If you consider the topologist's sine curve $(0,1)\to [-1,1]^2, x\mapsto {(x,\sin\frac1x)}$, it clearly fails to factor through $[0,1]$.